# linq query to share column x in var A from column y from var B

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to share 2 columns in 2 `IQueryable` variables.

I have the following 2 variables:

```
var leavingDays = resourcePlanningsInWeek.Where(rp => rp.Project.IsLeave);

var employeeRostersInWeek = employeeRostersExcludedHolidays
                .Where(rp => rp.RosterDate >= startDate &&
                             rp.RosterDate <= endDate);
```

I would like to do something like this:

> leavingDays.RosterHours / employeeRostersInWeek.DeploymentPlanned
>   where leavingDays.PlanDate equal employeeRostersInWeek.RosterDate

At the end I would like to sum all the values.

9/9 = 1

9/9 = 1

4,5/9 = 0,5

Result of the linq query (Sum all values) = 2,5

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
var result =
    (from l in leavingDays
        from r in employeeRostersInWeek
        where l.PlanDate == r.RosterDate
        select l.RosterHours / r.DeploymentPlanned
    ).Sum();
```

However, if `RosterHours` and `DeploymentPlanned` are defined as `int`s and you expect fractional results, then you should convert one of them to a fractional data type first, like so:

```
var result =
    (from l in leavingDays
        from r in employeeRostersInWeek
        where l.PlanDate == r.RosterDate
        select Convert.ToDouble(l.RosterHours) / r.DeploymentPlanned
    ).Sum();
```

Comment: this did not fix the problem. I see that the problem occurs when this calculation is executed:

8 / 0

Maybe I need to do this:

 result =
                                (from l in leavingDays
                                 from r in employeeRostersInWeek
                                 where l.PlanDate == r.RosterDate && r.RosterHours > 0
                                 select l.DeploymentPlanned / r.RosterHours
                                ).Sum();

Comment: @user1326231 you need to avoid dividing by `DeploymentPlanned` if it is `0`.

Comment: @user1326231 for example, you could replaec the `select` line with this: `select r.DeploymentPlanned == 0 ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(l.RosterHours) / r.DeploymentPlanned`

Comment: I've got now this error:

Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal. This is because I conert the result to a decimal:

decimal NoOfLeaveDays = Convert.ToDecimal(linq query discussed above);

Comment: @user1326231 try to inspect your values and see which one would produce this error (I assume it could be a very small `DeploymentPlanned` value)

Comment: one thing you could try is to use `Double` instead of `Decimal`